# App Store Rejection - "Policy 3.1.1" for External Mechanism, Need Advice

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ios-app-group

Recently, our app was rejected by the App Store citing "Policy 3.1.1" which relates to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions within the app. The App Store has requested that we remove the "user registration" feature from our app. However, this feature is essential for our startup.

Our app serves as a point-of-sale (POS) app and is an integral part of our main app (website) used by retailers and business owners. Currently, after users register, there are no further in-app payments required as payments are made directly via our website. Additionally, the mobile app does not contain any links or processes for in-app payments.

We are seeking advice from the community on how to effectively address the App Store's concerns and have our app accepted. Have any of you encountered a similar issue? Any recommendations on how to communicate with the App Store in a way that will help us resolve this situation would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Remove user registration from your app.  Presumably users are already registered via your web site.  They should simply be able to use that registration to log in to the mobile app.

Comment: A lot of services like this will forward users to a website to sign up. Netflix, Amazon, EBay, etc… they all use the app for purchases but for the sign up it is through a website.

Comment: @Fogmeister Do you know if I build an app uses fully webview and send to review, they(App store) will accept it? (if the app has flight ordering, tour searching and ordering functionalities) As you know there also, users will purchase something..
Sorry for out of topic question.